# ASP Source Code Map? Is there an easy way to generate this?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, code-generation

The company I work for, we have a number of web systems that are built in Classic ASP and ASP.NET 2.0.

I'm trying to tidy up the scripts folder as they are all sitting in the same place, and I've found some that are not even in use.

So, do any of you know if there is an easy way to generate something like a source code map? So I can easily see which one are not being referenced by any other script to make it easier to clean?

Also if I can generate this map, it would be great to start documenting this. As the previous developer was against documenting (believe it or not), and this is giving me lots of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if such tool exists but you could write a script that walks all files and searches in the contents of the sourcefiles if it is being loaded and not commented out (the last being the most difficult).

An easier way that i myself use is to load the different pages that are used in the webapp in Firefox with the Firebug add-on installed and activated (or a equivalent browser with the same functionality or plugin). On the Net tab of Firebug you see all the files that are loaded by a page and you can compare these with the folderstucture and contents.

If many pages need to be checked you can copy all url's with Ctrl-All , Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V it in an editor that is capable of sorting and removing duplicates so that you have a nice list of files being used a,nd can do your folder cleanup in one move.